# IIS(6) FTP site

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, ftp

We have a windows server 2003 with IIS(6). This is setup as our ftp server. We have the directory security setup to reject all ips except ones listed below. We have another server with ip xx.xx.xxx.xx, which is on the list for accepted ips. Yet the ftp server will not accept any incoming connections from this server. Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting iis admin service forced a restart of ftp publishing service. But it didn't bring the ftp publishing service back up. Bringing it backup fixed my problem.

Apparently whenever you modify the IP accept list you need to restart IIS. Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Instead of restarting the IISAdmin service (which will leave FTP, Web, etc. stopped), you could use the iisreset command, which will stop all IIS processes and then restore all services and sites to their former state when the command was issued.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of questions to help troubleshoot.

1) Can you ping the FTP server from the other server?
2) Have you attempted to telnet to port 21 from the second server to the FTP server?  If so, what is the result?
3) If you turn off directory security temporarily does that allow you to contact the FTP server?
4) Are you running Windows Firewall (Routing and Remote Access)?
5) Are there any errors in the Event Log?

Comment: I can ping the server. THe error in the event log is FTP server could not create a client worker thread for user at host xx.xx.xxx.xx. The connection to this user is terminated. The data is the error

Comment: telnet server 21. results in rejected connection unrecognized ip. If i turn off directory security by setting granted acces, will it remove all ips in the list? This ftp server hosts 15 other clients this one seems not to be able to get through. So i assume that the firewall should be fine.

Comment: Ok, if it is working for other servers then it probably isn't a firewall issue, and I don't suggest opening up the directory security because it might in fact delete the list.  Have you looked at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=mk;da-DK;862389bc6a9243f5b176056e41197048?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd9c312e-21f2-4219-bb3e-80397b618524.mspx?mfr=true) has one possible fix.
[Here's](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=293637) a knowledge base article that may help.

Either of them work?

Comment: it seems that >cscript adsutil.vbs enum msftpsvc/1/root shows my metabase is wrong. Being a lowly programmer I am not sure deleting the entire metabase is the solution. If i delete the metabase will i lose the entire list of accepted ip address?

Comment: +1 I would upvote you but i dont have 15 rep sorry

Comment: @george9170: that's okay :-) The metabase question, I don't know if it will or not. You might want to make sure you have the list handy in case they have to be re-entered.

Comment: restarting iis seems not to have any effect.